# Bootstrap panel not opening after collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the panel closing on a button click but when I click the button again, the panel won't open.

I have checked to make sure that I wasn't missing any closing tags and found that everything was fine.

Not sure what I missed.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myPanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="myPanel">
    Collapse
  </button>

<div id="VIDContactInfoWrapper" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="height:inherit;">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px 5px !important">Information</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="myPanel" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;height:300px; background-color:hotpink;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="VIContactInfo" class="col-md-6" style="background: white;"></div>
            <div id="VIAddressInfo" class="col-md-6" style="background: white;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is working as expected. The problem is that you're defining the height of the `panel-body` element with inline styling, which is getting overwritten when you use the Bootstrap toggle. To resolve this, just allow the content within `panel-body` to define the height, or define the height in external CSS instead:

```css
.panel-body {
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
  height:300px;
  background-color:hotpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myPanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="myPanel">
    Collapse
  </button>

<div id="VIDContactInfoWrapper" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="height:inherit;">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px 5px !important">Information</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="myPanel">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="VIContactInfo" class="col-md-6" style="background: white;"></div>
            <div id="VIAddressInfo" class="col-md-6" style="background: white;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this as answer because you provided an explanation as to what the issue was. However @imvain2 opening of the panel was more fluid and not as choppy as this way seems to be

Comment: @Chris That has to do with the other inline stylings you have in your code(background colors for your columns, etc). You should really try to define any styling in a stylesheet or inpage style tags. It's bad practice to put your CSS inline with your code.

Comment: Oh I am aware of that, this is just for testing things out before I put it live

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to wrap your panel-body in the collapsible div. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myPanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="myPanel">
    Collapse
  </button>

<div id="VIDContactInfoWrapper" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="height:inherit;">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px 5px !important">Information</div>
  <div  id="myPanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;height:300px; background-color:hotpink;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="VIContactInfo" class="col-md-6" style="background: white;"></div>
            <div id="VIAddressInfo" class="col-md-6" style="background: white;"></div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```